# Gitblit GO Setup X11 Driver HeadlessException

Tags: shell, installation, x11, opensuse, gitblit

these day i want do install the Gitblit GO Application on my openSuse x64 server.
But if i want to execute the ./authority.sh, i get this error:

Here u can see what i tried:

[image]

I also tried to set the DISPLAY variable to DISPLAY="MYIP":0.0, but there isnt really a difference.
My Server is installed without any x11 Driver or Graphics Frontend.

Now i have no clue, how i can install the GitLib GO version without installing graphics frontend to my server.

Pls Guys, im sorry for my bad english, and also for my bad linux know how :/

Greetz,

Comment: This is for http://superuser.com (see e.g. [this](http://superuser.com/questions/190801/linux-wmctrl-cannot-open-display-when-session-initiated-via-sshscreen)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of the Authority is optional.  Skip the Authority step and just start GO.  Gitblit will create a self-signed SSL certificate using default identification values.

The main reason to use the Authority is to setup an x.509 PKI infrastructure, but at this point you'd be better served by using the SSH infrastructure introduced in 1.5.0.  This transport and it's extendable command mechanism have become almost mandatory components.